# How to toggle on/off Shiny actionButton title? (and additional Settings in Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I want my `actionButton` to toggle between "Show filter options" and "Hide filter options" in its title, when I click on it. Ideally, also to change it's colour too.

Code below, does not work (it gives  `Error: argument is of length zero`)

```
renderUI(
  actionButton("button.filtering", 
               ifelse(
                 is.null(input$button.filtering), 
                 "Hide", 
                 ifelse ( input$button.filtering %% 2 == 1, "Hide", "Show" )
               ) )
)
```

Which one works?

I use this actionButton to show/hide additional Settings.
If you have any other (better) ideas to achieve the same - please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create you `actionButton` in the UI, then use e.g. an `observeEvent` to update the label in the server via `updateActionButton`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(
    "button.filtering",
    "Hide",
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button.filtering, {
    label <- if (input$button.filtering %% 2 == 0) "Hide" else "Show"
    
    updateActionButton(inputId = "button.filtering", label = label)  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```